# Getting SMTP timeout on one computer

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook-2007, smtp, timeout

One of the computers in the office is getting an SMTP connection timeout when trying to send e-mails.
All the others seem to work ok.
What could be the problem.

Using Outlook 2007 on Windows 7 Prof.

Comment: We need more information about your configuration. What Server are you trying to connect to? What differences are there between the computer with the error and the ones that work well? etc.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the error?